# Possibilites @mysql_affected_rows return Values?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please tell me what are all the possibilities of return values for @mysql_affected_rows. Because i am checking `if(@mysql_affected_rows())`. In most case it returns 1(sucess) or 0(not sucess). So it worked correctly. But in some cases it returns some value other than 0 if not success on updation.

I dont know what it returns. But it come into the loop. Inside loop i am trying to insert the data. But it shows duplication error on SQL for that. For your reference check the below code please,

```
$sqlU = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET count = count + 1
                            WHERE id = %d", 'table', 123);
mysql_query($sqlU);
if(!@mysql_affected_rows()) {
    $sqlI = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (id) VALUES (%d)",
                                'table', 123);
    mysql_query($sqlI);
}
```

Comment: why you using like `if(!@mysql_affected_rows()) {` ?

Comment: The PHP documentation tells you it returns number of affected rows or -1 on failure.. it's not that hard to get info without asking on SO. On the other hand, you're using a deprecated way of handling database communication, plus you're not checking whether your query succeeds or not - basically way too many bad things are going on in your code. You should look into PDO.

Comment: Your code also makes no sense. Why `UPDATE` a row and afterwards `INSERT` the same one again?

Comment: Why would you ask the same question twice, within two hours, when you already got the right answer in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

First, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) seems to return an integer in all cases. It returns `-1` if the query failed.

What you really need instead of `mysql_affected_rows()` is a proper query that is not open to race conditions.

`INSERT INTO table (id, count) VALUES (123, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1`