# Possible return values for mysql_affected_rows()

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please tell me what are all the possible return values for the function **mysql_affected_rows()**  **(while update)** in php? Also return values is for what circumstance?

**If update query didnt update anything or stops on error.Will it return -1 or 0? thats my question?**

Comment: if you look at the right side of your question you will see "Related" where your question has been replied already. And you're opening the same question multiple times that really not a good thing.

Comment: Is [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) really that hard to read? It has a big section titled "Return values".

Comment: Also, while you're on the manual page, take note of the big red box at the top that says you should avoid using the `mysql_xxx()` functions.

Comment: If update query didnt update anything will it return -1 or 0? thats my question?

Comment: @VinothBabu it will return 1 or more rows if update performs on existing rows.

Comment: there is no way of returning -1 in any circumstance? because i am facing some problem on it.

Comment: @VinothBabu If update query fails it will return -1.

Comment: fails mean. It will occur in which circumstance? (i.e) wrong query or ??

Comment: Duplicate of [Possibilites @mysql\_affected\_rows return Values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103917/possibilites-mysql-affected-rows-return-values)

Comment: @VinothBabu Insulting people here doesn't lead to the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FROM [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

> Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed.
>
> If the last query was a DELETE query with no WHERE clause, all of the records will have been deleted from the table but this function will return zero with MySQL versions prior to 4.1.2.
> When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query.
>
> The REPLACE statement first deletes the record with the same primary key and then inserts the new record. This function returns the number of deleted records plus the number of inserted records.
>
> In the case of "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" queries, the return value will be 1 if an insert was performed, or 2 for an update of an existing row.

Answer (score 4):

1. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2. mysql_affected_rows , search
3. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

> Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last
> query failed.
>
> If the last query was a DELETE query with no WHERE clause, all of the
> records will have been deleted from the table but this function will
> return zero with MySQL versions prior to 4.1.2.
>
> When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value
> is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that
> mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows
> matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the
> query.
>
> The REPLACE statement first deletes the record with the same primary
> key and then inserts the new record. This function returns the number
> of deleted records plus the number of inserted records.
>
> In the case of "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" queries, the
> return value will be 1 if an insert was performed, or 2 for an update
> of an existing row.

#### Important:

don't `use mysql_*` as is deprecated